# Webbrowser navigatostring() c# windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

When I try to navigate to this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" aslink="0" customdesign="0" data="http://www.tut.by/uppod/auppod.swf" width="580" height="327" id="swf1415721102817" style="visibility: visible;">
        <param name="id" value="swf1415721102817">
        <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"><param name="wmode" value="opaque">
        <param name="flashvars" value="m=video&amp;file=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Citp8jUXuiw&amp;uid=swf1415721102817&amp;auto=firstframe&amp;firstframe=2&amp;debug=0&amp;duration=0&amp;st=http://www.tut.by/uppod/frameid406/rek0/params.php?mode=swf%26file=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DCitp8jUXuiw%26uid=swf1415721102817&amp;comment=&amp;id=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Citp8jUXuiw"></object>
    </body>
</html>"
```

string in webbrowser control in windows phone 8 app. The player isn't displayed. How can I navigate to this string using navigatetostring() method?

Comment: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp8-wpapps/adobe-shockwave-for-windows-phone-htc8x/e68a2318-5486-42ba-bd6a-adc2a664b28b (might help)

Answer (score 0):

Flash isn't supported in the Windows Phone WebBrowser control (or in the browser, for that matter).